# Email looks strange in Outlook with DPI Scaling turned on

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

My HTML email template looks fine in Outlook without DPI scaling enabled on a computer, but when DPI scaling is enabled it doesn't look like it should. I've tried and implemented the solutions [here](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/151-mystery-solved-dpi-scaling-in-outlook-2007-2013) to no success.

You can see how the email looks like with DPI scaling [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tksn1.png). They should be two 300x300 boxes side by side.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
 <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <o:AllowPNG/>
 <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
 </xml><![endif]-->
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="format-detection" content="date=no" />
 <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />
 <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    
    <style>
 body { padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important; display:block !important; background:#ececec; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none }
 img {display:block;}
 table {border-collapse: collapse;}
 table td {mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;}
 @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #container {
   width:96% !important;
  }
  img {
   width:100% !important;
   height:auto !important;
  }
  .full-width {
   width:100% !important;
   height: auto !important;
   display:block !important;
   float:left !important;
 }
 
 </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ececec" style="background-color:#ececec;">

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-cellspacing: 0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px;width:100%;background-color:#ececec;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><center>
      
       <!-- start CONTAINER -->
        <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="container" style="width:600px;mso-cellspacing: 0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px;" align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    
                     <!-- start HEADING -->
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="30" style="mso-cellspacing: 0px; mso-padding-alt: 30px;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center">
                               <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center">
                                       <span style="font-size:32px;color:#AAAAAA;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;" class="searchResults"><b>SEARCH RESULTS FOR</b></span> &nbsp; <span style="font-size:32px;color:#ed1c24;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;" class="searchHashtag"><b>#HASHTAG</b></span>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- end HEADING -->
                        
                        <!-- start SQUARE BLOCK -->
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-cellspacing: 0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                               <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-cellspacing: 0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px;">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="50%" valign="top" class="full-width" style="width:300px;height:300px;"><img src="https://placehold.it/600" width="300" height="300" /></td>
                                      <td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle" class="full-width" bgcolor="#002442" style="width:300px;height:300px;background-color:#002442;">
                                       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" align="center" style="width:300px;mso-cellspacing: 0px; mso-padding-alt: 20px;" class="full-width">
                                         <tbody>
                                           <tr>
                                             <td valign="middle" align="center" width="100%"><a href="#" style="font-size: 28px; font-family: 'Arial'; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;line-height:100%;text-decoration:none;">TITLE HERE</a><br><br>
<a href="#" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Arial'; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: normal; text-align: center; text-decoration:none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ipsum magna, efficitur eget.</a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- end SQUARE BLOCK -->
                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- end CONTAINER -->
      
      </center></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```